# Is there any other option to get total count from table and distinct count of a column in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have table with 4 records with similar event name and 2 different device ids and i want total no. of records with total unique device ids.

Mysql gives perfect result but redshift is giving incorrect data.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  event_name varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
  deviceid int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (event_name, deviceid) VALUES
('install', 1),
('install', 1),
('install', 2),
('install', 1);

select count(event_name), count(distinct(deviceid)) from test;
```

Mysql result

[image]

Comment: what is the output of redshift ???

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Distinct` without `(` `)`

```
SELECT count(event_name), COUNT(Distinct deviceid) 
FROM Test;
```

**Or**

```
SELECT count(event_name), (SELECT count(deviceid) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM test)) DisCount
FROM test;
```

Comment: I need only one row with total count and total count of distinct devices

Comment: added image in question.

Comment: redshift is not giving same output as mysql, it give count = 4 and distinct count = 4

Comment: i don't want to use two queries or sub query.

Comment: @PavanSikarwar Try the updated answer `SELECT count(event_name), COUNT(Distinct deviceid) FROM Test;`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Redshift should process this query correctly:

```
select count(event_name), count(distinct deviceid)
from test;
```

That said, in my experience with RedShift, `count(distinct)` was quite slow, particularly over an entire table.  (This may be been fixed.)

If this is still the case, then a simple workaround is:

```
select sum(cnt) as row_count, count(*) as distinct_count
from (select deviceid, count(*) as cnt
      from test
      group by deviceid
     ) t
```

This might be significantly faster.